# Why this online game go out of sync after some time?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, iocp, online-game

I'm making a simple online game and I'm suffering from out-of-sync issues. The server is implemented with IOCP, and since the game will be held almost always in LAN, the delay is relatively small.

The core algorithm of network connecting can be described as below: (There are 4 clients in a single fame)

- Clients send their actions and the elasped time since the last frame to the server every frame, then wait until get a response from the server.
- The server collects all four clients' messages, concatenate them together, then send it to all four clients.
- On receiving the response, clients update their game with the messages provided in the response.

Now, I can see that after some time the four games go out of sync. It can be observed that the game I'm controling is different from the other three(which means the other three are the same), and just by walking around makes the problem happen.

Below is the code, if it might be helpful:

First, the server. Every message will be handled in a separate thread.

```
    while(game_host[now_roomnum].Ready(now_playernum)) // wait for the last message to be taken away
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    game_host[now_roomnum].SetMessage(now_playernum, recv_msg->msg);
    game_host[now_roomnum].SetReady(now_playernum, true);
    game_host[now_roomnum].SetUsed(now_playernum, false);
    while(!game_host[now_roomnum].AllReady()) // wait for all clients' messages
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    string all_msg = game_host[now_roomnum].GetAllMessage();
    game_host[now_roomnum].SetUsed(now_playernum, true);
    while(!game_host[now_roomnum].AllUsed()) // wait for all four responses are ready to send
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }
    game_host[now_roomnum].SetReady(now_playernum, false);// ready for receiving the next message

    strcpy_s(ret.msg, all_msg.c_str());
```

And the clients' `CGame::Update(float game_time)` method:

```
CMessage msg = MakeMessage(game_time);//Make a message with the actions taken in the frame(pushed into a queue) and the elasped time between the two frames
CMessage recv = p_res_manager->m_Client._SendMessage(msg);//send the message and wait for the server's response
stringstream input(recv.msg);
int i;

rest_time -= game_time;
float game_times[MAX_PLAYER+1]={0};

//analyze recv operations
for(i=1; i<=MAX_PLAYER; i++)
{
    int n;
    input>>n;
    input>>game_times[i];//analyze the number of actions n, and player[i]'s elasped game time game_times[i]
    for(int oper_i = 1; oper_i <= n; oper_i++)
    {
        int now_event;
        UINT nchar;
        input>>now_event>>nchar;

        if(now_event == int(Event::KEY_UP))
            HandleKeyUpInUpdate(i, nchar);
        else //if(now_event == int(Event::KEY_DOWN))
            HandleKeyDownInUpdate(i, nchar);
    }
}

//update player
for(i=1; i<=MAX_PLAYER; i++)
{
    player[i].Update(game_times[i]);//something like s[i] = v[i] * game_time[i]
}
```

Thank you very much. I'll provide more detail if necassary.

Answer (score 0):

Ur general design is wrong, that's why u get async at some point. The server should never ever deal with the fps of the clients. This is just a horrible design issue. On general the server calculates everything regarding on the input's the clients send to server. And the clients just request the current status of their surroundings of the server. That way u are fps independent on the server side. Which mean u can update the scene on the server as fast as possible, and the clients just retrieve the current status.

When u update the entities on the server fps dependent per user, u would have to keep a local copy of every entity for every client, otherwise it's impossible to transfer for different delta times.

The other design could be that ur server just syncs the clients, so every client calculates the scene on it's own and then send their status to the server. The server then distributes this to the other clients, and the clients decide what to do with this information.

Any other design will lead to major problems, i highly regret to not use any other design.

if u have any further questions feel free to contact me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I did not save any copies on the server, I use the second design as you mentioned. The server did not deal with clients' fps issues as well. Afterwards, I found that the real problem is the racing condition issue. My `While()` loop fails to sync the threads as I expected. Later, I changed `while`s to semaphores, and the problems is solved. Thank you for your answer anyway, I learnt more from this problem now.